# How to install the win32com python library

Tags: python, windows, microsoft-outlook

I am trying to install the win32com module. I know I should download the [Python for Windows extension](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/), but it does not work.

After I have installed Python for Windows and try `import win32com.client`, I get the following error message:

```
>>> import win32com.client

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
        import win32com.client
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
        import win32api, sys, os

ImportError: No module named win32api
```

Trying to google for help on how to install win32api for Python does not help either; I am just referred to the Python for Windows extensions again.

Comment: Did you install the right binary of Python for Windows extensions for your version of Python? For example, if you install 64-bit Python, then install the 32-bit extensions, the pure-Python modules (like `win32con`) will import, but the C-extension modules (like `win32api`) will not; if you install Python 2.6, then install the extensions for 2.7, they may import but crash later; etc.

Comment: Why on Earth was this migrated from Stack Overflow?!

Answer (score 31):

1. Start a command line with admin rights.
2. `python -m pip install pywin32`
3. `C:\Program Files\Stackless36\Scripts>python pywin32_postinstall.py -install`
   The path `C:\Program Files\Stackless36\` should be replaced with the
   path at which your Python version is installed.
4. Test (admin rights optional) using `python -c "import win32com"` or `python speak.py`

   where `speak.py` consists of this text:

   ```python
   import win32com.client

   speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
   speaker.Speak("It works. Hoorah!")
   ```

Working fine on Python 3.6.4 Stackless 3.1b3 060516 (v3.6.4-slp:9557b2e530, Dec 21 2017, 15:23:10) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32. Vanilla CPython hangs out here:

```
C:\Users\C\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32>python.exe
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import win32com.client
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
>>> exit()

C:\Users\C\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32>python.exe -m pip install pywin32
Collecting pywin32
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/2d/b927e61c4a2b0aaaab72c8cb97cf748c319c399d804293164b0c43380d5f/pywin32-223-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl (8.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 8.3MB 50kB/s
Installing collected packages: pywin32
Successfully installed pywin32-223
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Answer (score 4):

Check sys.path to make sure the directory where the module is installed is in there, otherwise you have to add it (google PYTHONPATH windows for some help with that.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The problem turned out to be something different: for some reason there were two different Python installations in the registry, though both pointing to the same files. Re-installing it on both solved the problem.

Comment: I tried setting up PYTHONPATH in environment variable and still dont see this working. getting same error.

Comment: For those of you who now installed the package that OP linked, you'll need to restart your Python console (e.g. IDLE) for necessary changes to PYTHONPATH to populate such that your `import` will work.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem only yesterday. I installed `pypiwin32` using `pip`.

Try

```
>>pip install -U pypiwin32
```

at the command prompt

Make sure your Python package is in the system PATH.

Note that there are a few different ways to install Python modules, and as you have discovered not all of them work. `pip install` with `-U` worked for me with the `pypiwin32` module (which contains `win32com`).

Comment: The `-U` switch stands for `--upgrade` and https://pypi.org/project/pypiwin32/ is a better-packed (.whl format) https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/ by the same devs. I read that `python -m pip` is preferred to just `pip` for path reasons.

Comment: This worked for me. Note that if you are receiving the error message, `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`, try: `python -m pip install -U pypiwin32`

Comment: Might be worth exploring the difference between both packages to see which one is appropriate for any user reading this answer: pywin32, pypiwin32

Answer (score -2):

look for the file in your computer by searching in all your computer "win32api" once you find it put it here C:\Python26\Lib\win32com  "this suppossed you already install win32com library and you will find the file I think in" C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\win32  "After all the file should be located in those two places in your computer for your module to work that's it in fini".