# Error with Python win32com

Tags: python, python3, pycharm, python3.2

I have installed Python 3.6.5 in  Windows 10 and tried to import `win32com.client`, but I'm getting the following error message:

```
import win32com.client

Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
```

When I gone through online, I found a similar issue. But the solutions given  didn't help me. Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/609447/how-to-install-the-win32com-python-library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install the win32com python library](https://superuser.com/questions/609447/how-to-install-the-win32com-python-library)